# Установка OpenCV

Tags: opencv, anaconda

Я пытаюсь установить библиотеку OpenCV, которая уже была в Anaconda3, но при работе пишет, что такого модуля не существует.[image: ошибка кода]

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, она была связана с тем, что на MacOS предустановлен python2.7, и OpenCV установился туда. Надо было зайти в настройки PyCharm и в настройках данного проекта вручную установить opencv-python.